# XML wont load content through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I'm trying to load an xml file using ajax. I tried to modify the example of [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_xml.asp)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showBus(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getbus.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>Select your bus route:
            <select name="NUMBER" onchange="showBus(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select a Bus:</option>
                <option value="102">102</option>
            </select>
            <div id="txtHint"><b>Bus info will be listed here...</b>
            </div>
        </form>
```

```php
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("routes.xml");
    $x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $x->length - 1; $i++) {
        //Process only element nodes
        if ($x->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
            if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
                $y = ($x->item($i)->parentNode);
            }
        }
    }

    $BUS = ($y->childNodes);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $BUS->length; $i++) {
        //Process only element nodes
        if ($BUS->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
            echo("<b>" . $BUS->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
            echo($BUS->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
            echo("<br>");
        }
    }
?>
```

XML File:

```
<TT>
    <BUS>
        <NUMBER>102</NUMBER>
        <DEPARTING_STOP>102</DEPARTING_STOP>
        <DESTINATION>102</DESTINATION>
        <TIME>102</TIME>
    </BUS>
</TT>
```

This is what I get when I select the bus number from drop down menu:

```
Select your bus route:
load("routes.xml"); $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER'); for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++) { //Process only element nodes if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1) { if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) { $y=($x->item($i)->parentNode); } } } $BUS=($y->childNodes); for ($i=0;$i<$BUS->length;$i++) { //Process only element nodes if ($BUS->item($i)->nodeType==1) { echo("" . $BUS->item($i)->nodeName . ": "); echo($BUS->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue); echo("
"); } } ?>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions properly so that they are easily readable. It will help you in getting a quicker and more accurate answer if other humans can read your code.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Open `<yourserver>getbus.php?q=102` in your browser. Do you get something like this:

```
NUMBER: 102
DEPARTING_STOP: 102
DESTINATION: 102
TIME: 102
```

If you get something like:

```
load("routes.xml"); $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('NUM...
```

I'd personally think you are not running an http server but are excuting everything locally. 
Your getbus.php file is a php sourceode file that needs to be interpreted by a php processor. This is all being done by a webserver (if correctly configured). To get started you can use xampp ( https://www.apachefriends.org/ ) which has all the necessary modules for your sample. It is a preconfigured server to run php.

Then put all your files in the according htdocs folder in your xampp installation and the sample should work.

EDIT: 
As it seems the getbus.php most of the time responses with an empty response. The problem apears to be the load(file) method by domdocument. loadXML seems to work better. So this always works for me:

```
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->loadXML("<TT>
    <BUS>
        <NUMBER>102</NUMBER>
        <DEPARTING_STOP>102</DEPARTING_STOP>
        <DESTINATION>102</DESTINATION>
        <TIME>102</TIME>
    </BUS>
     <BUS>
        <NUMBER>103</NUMBER>
        <DEPARTING_STOP>104</DEPARTING_STOP>
        <DESTINATION>105</DESTINATION>
        <TIME>107</TIME>
    </BUS>
</TT>");
    $x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $x->length - 1; $i++) {
        //Process only element nodes
        if ($x->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
            if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
                $y = ($x->item($i)->parentNode);
            }
        }
    }

    $BUS = ($y->childNodes);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $BUS->length; $i++) {
        //Process only element nodes
        if ($BUS->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
            echo("<b>" . $BUS->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
            echo($BUS->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
            echo("<br>");
        }
    }
```

note that the entire XML file is now inside the PHP file as a string. To make it working the way you want you could try to load the file contents into a string using file() or file_get_contents() in the php file.

Comment: I am runnign it locally, but also on cloud9 ide which has apache built in

Comment: Which response do you get?